# react search filter query using laravel

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, api

I have been trying to implement a search filter query for my table of vfis using React and Laravel with an API. The below code is where the search form resides.

Navbar.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Link, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import swal from 'sweetalert';
import axios from 'axios';
// import Vfi from '../../components/admin/vfi/Vfi';

function Navbar() {

    const history = useHistory();
    const logoutSubmit = (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
    
    axios.post(`/api/logout`).then(res => {
        if(res.data.status === 200)
        {
            localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
            localStorage.removeItem('auth_name');
            swal("Success",res.data.message,"success");
            history.push('/');
        }
    });
 }

 var AuthButtons = '';
 if(!localStorage.getItem('auth_token'))
 {
     AuthButtons = (
         <ul className="navbar-nav">
             <li className="nav-item">
                 <Link className="nav-link" to="/login">Login</Link>
             </li>
             <li className="nav-item">
                 <Link className="nav-link" to="/register">Register</Link>
             </li>
             <li className="nav-item">
                 <Link className="nav-link" to="/contact">Contact</Link>
             </li>
         </ul>
     );
 }
 else
 {
     AuthButtons = (
         <li className="nav-item">
             <li><Link className="dropdown-item" onClick={logoutSubmit}>Logout</Link></li>
         </li>
     );
 }

    return (
        <nav className="sb-topnav navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-mycolor">
        <Link className="navbar-brand ps-3" to="/admin">VFI Kenya</Link>

        <button className="btn btn-link btn-sm order-1 order-lg-0 me-4 me-lg-0" id="sidebarToggle" href="#!"><i className="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
      
        <form className="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ms-auto me-0 me-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
      <div className="input-group">
      <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search for..." aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
    
    <button className="btn btn-primary" id="btnNavbarSearch" type="button"><i className="fas fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
    </form>

        <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto ms-md-0 me-3 me-lg-4">
            <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                <Link to="#" className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown"  role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i className="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i>
                    </Link>
                    <ul className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><Link className="dropdown-item" to="#!">Settings</Link></li>
                    <li><Link className="dropdown-item" to="#!">Activity Log</Link></li>
                    <li><hr className="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                    {AuthButtons}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

This is my laravel code for the controller am using...

VFiController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Models\Vfi;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class VFiController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $vfis = Vfi::all();
        return response()->json([
            'status'=> 200,
            'vfis'=>$vfis,
        ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        //    'TelNo' => 'required|regex:/(0)[0-9]{9}/',
           'LengthofMembershipinVFi'=> 'required|integer',
           'firstName'=> 'required|unique:vfis| |min:2',
           'secondName'=> 'required|unique:vfis| |min:2',
           'Email'=> 'required|unique:vfis| |email',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return response()->json([
                'status'=> 422,
                'validate_err'=> $validator->messages(),
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
           
        $vfi = new Vfi() ;
        $vfi->Gender = $request->input('Gender') ;
        $vfi->firstName = $request->input('firstName') ;
        $vfi->secondName = $request->input('secondName') ;
        $vfi->MaritalStatus = $request->input('MaritalStatus') ;
        $vfi->TelNo= $request->input('TelNo') ;
        $vfi->TownofResidence = $request->input('TownofResidence') ;
        $vfi->Fellowshipifattendingany = $request->input('Fellowshipifattendingany') ;
        $vfi->MinistryInvolvedin= $request->input('MinistryInvolvedin') ;
        $vfi->ChurchYouattend = $request->input('ChurchYouattend') ;
        $vfi->Profession = $request->input('Profession') ;
        $vfi->LengthofMembershipinVFi = $request->input('LengthofMembershipinVFi') ;
        $vfi->Email = $request->input('Email') ;
        $vfi->save();

            return response()->json([
                'status'=> 200,
                'message'=>'Thank you for your response!',
            ]);
        }

    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $vfi = Vfi::find($id);
        if($vfi)
        {
            return response()->json([
                'status'=> 200,
                'vfi' => $vfi,
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json([
                'status'=> 404,
                'message' => 'No vfi ID Found',
            ]);
        }

    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        // 'TelNo' => 'required|regex:/(0)[0-9]{9}/',
        //'LengthofMembershipinVFi'=> 'required|integer',
        //'firstName'=> 'required|unique:vfis| |min:2',
        //'secondName'=> 'required|unique:vfis| |min:2',
        //'Email'=> 'required|unique:vfis| |email',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return response()->json([
                'status'=> 422,
                'validationErrors'=> $validator->messages(),
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            $vfi = Vfi::find($id);
            if($vfi)
            {

                
        $vfi = Vfi::find($id);
        $vfi->Gender = $request->input('Gender') ;
        $vfi->firstName = $request->input('firstName') ;
        $vfi->secondName = $request->input('secondName') ;
        $vfi->MaritalStatus = $request->input('MaritalStatus') ;
        $vfi->TelNo= $request->input('TelNo') ;
        $vfi->TownofResidence = $request->input('TownofResidence') ;
        $vfi->Fellowshipifattendingany = $request->input('Fellowshipifattendingany') ;
        $vfi->MinistryInvolvedin= $request->input('MinistryInvolvedin') ;
        $vfi->ChurchYouattend = $request->input('ChurchYouattend') ;
        $vfi->Profession = $request->input('Profession') ;
        $vfi->LengthofMembershipinVFi = $request->input('LengthofMembershipinVFi') ;
        $vfi->Email = $request->input('Email') ;
        $vfi->save();

                return response()->json([
                    'status'=> 200,
                    'message'=>'Updated Successfully',
                ]);
            }
            else
            {
                return response()->json([
                    'status'=> 404,
                    'message' => 'No Vfi ID Found',
                ]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $vfi = Vfi::find($id);
        if($vfi)
        {
            $vfi->delete();
            return response()->json([
                'status'=> 200,
                'message'=>'Vfi Deleted Successfully',
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json([
                'status'=> 404,
                'message' => 'No Vfi ID Found',
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

And my api.php from laravel

```
Route::get('vfis', [VFiController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/add-vfi', [VFiController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/edit-vfi/{id}', [VFiController::class, 'edit']);
Route::put('update-vfi/{id}', [VFiController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('delete-vfi/{id}', [VFiController::class, 'destroy']);
```

[image: The table vfis with the search form]

Could someone show me how I can make the search form query and filter data from my table vfis  where the data is already presented on the React end using an API

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search in all fields, you can alter your search function like

```
public function search($key)
{
   return Vfi::where('name','ILIKE',"%$key%")
   ->orWhere('Gender','ILIKE',"%$key%")
   ->orWhere('firstName','ILIKE',"%$key%")
   ->orWhere('secondName','ILIKE',"%$key%")
   ->orWhere('TownofResidence','ILIKE',"%$key%")
   ->orWhere('ChurchYouattend','ILIKE',"%$key%")
->get();
}
```

You can add all the fields where you want to search your $key.
Remember ILIKE is for case sensitive problems in sql, But it will not work for MySQL.
You can use the LOWER() function for MySQL,

```
->orWhere('LOWER(ChurchYouattend)','LIKE',"%$key%")
```

And another best approach to filter the result is through laravel pipeline.
You can see how to use pipeline [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72417176/laravel-loop-data-filtering-in-where-clauses).

Comment: ok, what code will I write in React js remember am using an api. So look at my Navbar.js

Comment: Does "ILIKE" work with MySQL also?

Comment: No, ILIKE does not work for MySQL, We can user the LOWER() function for MySQL.

Comment: What about the React Js code where we have the search code in the Navbar.js what should I write to call the API from Laravel so as to filter the results

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Haris solution, which might not work with MySql. To handle case-sensitive problem, we can use `LOWER`

```
public function search($key)
{
   return Vfi::where('LOWER(name)','LIKE',"%".$key."%")
   ->orWhere('LOWER(Gender)','LIKE',"%".$key."%")
   ->orWhere('LOWER(firstName)','LIKE',"%".$key."%")
   ->orWhere('LOWER(secondName)','LIKE',"%"/$key."%")
   ->orWhere('LOWER(TownofResidence)','LIKE',"%".$key."%")
   ->orWhere('LOWER(ChurchYouattend)','LIKE',"%".$key."%")
->get();
}
```